# Dynamic choropleth, with time slider or auto playing

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to replicate [this map](https://www.darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/breathing-city/):

[image]

which alternates showing housing and employment densities in NYC through the day, in R.

I have spatial object, `S`, with census small area polygons and two variables,
inhabitants  (`S@data$pop`) and employment (`S@data$emp`), for each area.

As in the example, I would like to have two "extreme" cases:

1. choropleth  of only `S@data$pop`, in blue, dominant at midnight.
2. choropleth  of only `S@data$emp`, in red, dominant at noon.

and some 'intermediate' plots to make a smooth transition between "1." and "2.".

And I would like the result to "auto play", e. i., keep repeating the cycle between "1." and "2.".

I imagine I could do this with ggplot2 + shiny, having a time slider control the time of the day. And perhaps somehow automate, or autoplay the time variable. Is this doable in shiny (or some other R solution)?

Comment: let me google that for you... http://rmaps.github.io/blog/posts/animated-choropleths/

Comment: @cory: tks a lot, I had googled but missed that tutorial. This will solve 90% of the issues (I'll still need to make plots that integrate the blue and red chanels)